How can I run more than two Thread to parse multiple documents with DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient - python
As such, the code works, but only with two Threads, if I add another one, the process stops and then takes a time out. I don't know if DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient will have a limit of two threads at a time, although most likely I am doing something wrong.
async def get_text_ocr(file_path):
    try:
        tipo = str(file_path).split('.')[-1]
        if tipo.upper() =='PDF':
            mime_type = 'application/'+str(file_path).split('.')[-1]
        else:
            mime_type = 'image/'+str(file_path).split('.')[-1]

        print(mime_type)
        #client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(
        client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient(
            client_options=ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f'{location}-{endpoint}')
        )
        

        name = client.processor_version_path(project_id,location,processor_id,processor_version)
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as pag:
            image_content = pag.read()
        
        raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(
            content = image_content, mime_type=mime_type
        )
        request =  documentai.ProcessRequest(name=name, raw_document=raw_document)
        response = await client.process_document(request=request)
        document = response.document
        return document.text
    except Exception as exp:
        print(exp)
        return None


def procesar_documentos(archivos_leer,Carpeta_destino, hilo_cc):
    carpeta_igual=str(archivos_leer[0]).split('/')[5]
    for archivo in archivos_leer:
        carpeta_actual = (str(archivo).split('/')[5])
        nueva_ruta = str(archivo).split('/')[:-1]
        nueva_ruta.append("Identificados")
        nueva_ruta = '/'.join(nueva_ruta)
        if carpeta_actual != carpeta_igual:
            hola = str("/").join(str(archivo).split('/')[:5])+"/"
            system(f'move "{hola+carpeta_igual}" "{Carpeta_destino}"')
            carpeta_igual = carpeta_actual
        txt = mija(archivo)
    system(f'move "{hola+carpeta_igual}" "{Carpeta_destino}"')
    print('Finalizado')


def mija(file_path):
    return asyncio.run(get_text_ocr(file_path))

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=procesar_documentos, args=(hilos[0],Carpeta_destino,"hilo_1"), name="Hilo 1")
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=procesar_documentos, args=(hilos[1],Carpeta_destino,"hilo_2"), name="Hilo 2")

deseo poder utilizar como mínimo 4 hilos para procesar documentos 4 DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient al tiempo

it looks like the code in the question needs a massive edit.
